# AddComment does not work when using With Range("F15")

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to place some comments and values into a range of cells like this:

```
With Range("B5:C8")
   .AddComment "Current Sales"
End With
```

when I do that I get an error Run-time error "5": Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

When I try this:

```
With Range("B5:C8")
   .Value = 35
End With
```

it works fine, Is there something about the AddComment that works differently?

I'm using Excel 365 on Windows 10

Thanks for any help

Comment: `AddComment` requires the range to be a single cell. You will also get an error if the cell already has a comment. `F15` was in your subject, but not part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a range with multiple cells, you will need a loop.

Also, since you cannot add more than one comment, you will need to replace it by deleting the original one first, or you can append the new comment to the old comment.

```
Sub AddCellComment(FullRange As Range, cmt As String, Optional Replace As Boolean = False)
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    
    For Each r In FullRange
        If r.Comment Is Nothing Then
            r.AddComment cmt
        Else
            ' (cannot set .Text directly)
            ' save original comment into a variable
            s = r.Comment.Text
            ' delete original comment
            r.Comment.Delete
            
            If Replace Then
                ' replace original comment
                r.AddComment cmt
            Else
                ' append new comment
                r.AddComment s & vbCrLf & cmt
            End If
            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Usage**

```
Sub test()
    AddCellComment Range("B5:C8"), "test"
   ' also works with F15 (per your subject)
    AddCellComment Range("F15"), "test"
   ' to replace, add True as another argument
    AddCellComment Range("B5:C8"), "test", True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I guess what I find frustrating is that MS documentation does not say that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.addcomment?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144222);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue  they say range like any other Range. That's why having you guys to help is so great!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each cell ...

```
Dim objCell As Range

For Each objCell In Range("B5:C8")
   objCell.AddComment "Current Sales"
Next
```

... error checking ommitted.